# Java 8 HashMap - Is the default treeify threshold value '8' because that is the point when O(logn) lookup becomes faster than O(n)?

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap, big-o, red-black-tree

We all know the lovely internals of Java 8's HashMap but its default treeify value got me thinking.

LinkedList is preferred over an array for a bucket as an array needs a pre-determined size and the chance of collisions is very low. Amortised insert doesn't become O(1) until after the first few resizes, so LinkedList makes sense for low values of N in this case.

However, why is the bucket data structure changed to a Red-Black tree after 8 objects have been added? Is it because this is the exact point where O(logn) lookup time becomes faster than O(n) for a Java HashMap?

**::edit::**

Stephen C has identified that there is a trade-off between lookup speed and space utilisation and that a TreeNode occupies twice the space of a Node, as per the javadoc.

Following on from this, my question is: Does the space utilisation overhead become less important than what is made up in gains of access speed of O(logN) vs O(N) after 8 objects are added? Is there a way to plot time complexity vs space utilisation for different values of N to visualise this trade-off?